# SQL count after joining two tables

Tags: sql, count

I am newbie to SQL, I would like to come up with a count, assume this example with 2 tables:

```
School(schoolID, name,....)
Student(StudentID, SchoolID, ...)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(studentID) 
FROM School s, Student t
WHERE s.schooldID = t.schoolID
```

How can I get a count of all students across all schools?

Comment: aren't all students already in the Student table? why do you need to join with the school?

Comment: Because there are lots of schools, I want to sum number of all students in all schools?

Comment: You just need to do is COUNT(STUDENTID) GROUP BY SCHOOLID

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the school ID in the student table, it doesn't appear to me that you need to join to school at all. Just select a count from the student table and group by schoolID:

```
SELECT schoolID, COUNT(*) AS numStudents
FROM student
GROUP BY schoolID;
```

The only reason you'd need to join to School is if you want other information, such as school name and so on. If you just want the school id and number of students, the above will work.

To complete that last thought, possibly irrelevant to your question. If you did want school name, you just do an inner join and put `school.name` in your select statement, along with the count from the student table and group by school ID still:

```
SELECT s.name, st.COUNT(*) AS numStudents
FROM student st
JOIN school s ON s.id = st.schoolID
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the count *per school*, you need a `group by`. Also, usually we prefer ANSI style joins, since in fact all database systems support them nowadays and they easier to read and maintain:

```
select count(t.studentID)
from   Student t
join   School s /* added join for your convenience, not necessary here */
on     s.schooldID = t.schooldID
group
by     t.schoolID
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, surprisingly What I tried in my original post also worked, I thought I was doing it wrong, but I guess not.

Comment: I think there's a syntax error here, it should just be `ON` not `ON WHERE`

Comment: It gets the best of all of us. I assume *most* people would have caught it pretty quickly, but it might throw a new guy for a loop.

Comment: @user1529412: Need more help?